# How to get the path of tag if it has a space in its class or id

Tags: html, jquery, cheerio

I am trying to get the path of the tags with class name(using cheerio). I tried

```
let title =$('div.group-flag > div >a').text();
```

this works fine.
I am trying to get `text required`.

I tried

```
let title=$('//span[starts-with(@class,"js-course-title")]')
```

this gives an error.

```
$('span[class="js-course-title.d-none.d-sm-block"]')
```

this returns no values (or `length=0`). Please let me know how can I get the text required?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your class and id names to remove the spaces.

An `id` cannot contain a space. See [MDN on id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id): *"id's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.)."*

A class list associated with an element is a **space-separated** list, so it makes no sense to include whitespace in a class name. See [MDN on classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)

Comment: Hi thanks for the docs I still am not getting it may be I am wrong in the path, for an example I have <span class="c-ad-carousel__subtitle c-ad-carousel__subtitle--location c-ad-carousel__subtitle--small">Bochum</span>                                                              $('span[class="cadcarouselsubtitlecadcarouselsubtitlelocationcadcarouselsubtitlesmall"]')                                                                                                                                  Can you please let me know what the path should be?

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
$('[class="c-ad-carousel__subtitle c-ad-carousel__subtitle--location c-ad-carousel__subtitle--small"]')
```

Or

```
$('.c-ad-carousel__subtitle.c-ad-carousel__subtitle--location.c-ad-carousel__subtitle--small')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not working. Please let me know if there are any other combinations

Comment: If it's not working it means it's not really there. You should check the html.